# How to load rad autocomplete textbox from database with text and value in a block

Tags: c#

```
public void LoadDiseaes()
        {           
            da.OpenConnection();
            Disease disease = new Disease(da);
            txtDisease.AutoCompleteDataSource = disease.GetAll();
            txtDisease.AutoCompleteDisplayMember ="DiseaseName";
            txtDisease.AutoCompleteValueMember ="ID";
        }
```

Intially I have used code above to bind autocomplete TextBox `txtDisease` with its Datasource.

Then after I select particular disease as it appears above and save the record, still this works fine. But my question is that when I want to update that record I want to populate my AutoComplete `txtDisease` with the Disease from the Database with its Text and Value in a block which I have selected during saving the record. I am just able to retrieve the text but it does return value in background ?

Comment: Can you be more explain more your question, it's not really clear.

Comment: I just want that the autotextbox  dispalys the records which I have choosen during saving record when I want to do  update opeartion  on that record?